# how to add and remove css class

Tags: jquery

how to remove CSS default class

This is my div

```
<div id="messageContainer">
```

This is my css class

```
#messageContainer{  
  height:26px;  
  color:#FFFFFF;    
  BACKGROUND-COLOR: #6af; 
  VERTICAL-ALIGN: middle;
  TEXT-ALIGN: center;
  PADDING-TOP:6px;  
}
```

I want to remove default class and new css class

Please help;

Comment: +1..becouse it is new for me..and simple

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can approach it two ways. One, use two classes and literally swap them out for each other:

```
.red { background: red }
.green { background: green }
```

And then in jQuery:

```
$("#messageContainer").attr('class','green'); // switch to green
$("#messageContainer").attr('class','red'); // switch to red
```

**Or** you can use CSS order to toggle a single class:

```
#messageContainer { background: red }
#messageContainer.green { background: green }
```

Then:

```
$("#messageContainer").toggleClass("green");
```

That would alternate backgrounds every time it was called.

Answer (score 4):

You aren't dealing with a class. You have default rules applied to the ID element. As such, you should really only need to add the new class:

```
$("#messageContainer").addClass("newRules");
```

Any rules that aren't overwritten can be overwritten with the `css()` method:

```
$("#messageContainer").css({
  'font-weight':'bold',
  'color':'#990000'
}).addClass("newRules");
```

Comment: Should be `addClass("newRules");` - no dot.

Comment: Thanks @Kobi. I seem to always initially use selector-syntax when writing a classname :(

Answer (score 2):

You are not defining a css class in your example, you are using the selector for the id.

to use a class your code would be like:

```
<div id="messageContainer" class="messageContainer"></div>
```

and in your stylesheet or between style tags you would have

```
.messageContainer{  
  height:26px;  
  color:#FFFFFF;    
  BACKGROUND-COLOR: #6af; 
  VERTICAL-ALIGN: middle;
  TEXT-ALIGN: center;
  PADDING-TOP:6px;  
}
```

then, using jquery you could remove this class by doing

```
$('#messageContainer').removeClass('messageContainer');
```

Answer (score 1):

For IE10 and up use these methods:

```
// adds class "foo" to el
el.classList.add("foo");

// removes class "foo" from el
el.classList.remove("foo");

// toggles the class "foo"
el.classList.toggle("foo");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a period before your css class definition.

Using your example above you should use:

```
.messageContainer{
height:26px;    
color:#FFFFFF;  
BACKGROUND-COLOR: #6af; 
VERTICAL-ALIGN: middle;
TEXT-ALIGN: center;
PADDING-TOP:6px;    
}
```