# jquery count the elements by class and set the another class a certain element in the list

Tags: javascript, jquery

How with jQuery/Javascript count the elements by class and set another class a certain element in the list.

It is possible?

An example, i have four elements with the class "qa" and change or add class "qa2" second element in list.

Comment: Are you having a particular problem? What have you *tried* to do, any research at all? What went wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery count child elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4291151/jquery-count-child-elements) and [how to add and remove css class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2170878/how-to-add-and-remove-css-class).

Comment: Also you can find solutions to most of your problems in the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Using jquery**

```
var el = $('.cls');
alert(el.length); // Will alert length
```

To add a class to the 2nd element

```
$(el[1]).addClass('classOne'); // first item is 0 and second item is 1 and so on
```

Inside a loop to add class to 2nd element using condition.

```
el.each(function(i){
    if(i==1) // If 2nd item then add the class
        $(el[i]).addClass('newClass');  
});​
```

Or this will add 'newClass' class to all elements that has class 'cls'

```
$('.cls').addClass('newClass')​;
```

OR this will add different classes to odd and even items in the list/matched items

```
​$('.cls').each(function(i){
    if(!(i%2))  
        $(this).addClass('odd');
    else
        $(this).addClass('even');
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

Relatively easy:

```
var numOfElementsOfClassName = $('.classNameToFind').length;
var particularIndexToApplyNewClass = 3;
$('.classNameToFind').eq(particularIndexToApplyNewClass).addClass('newClassName');
```

References:

- [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).
- [`eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/).

Comment: And maybe need remove the old class with `removeClass()`.

Comment: I considered that, but I couldn't work out, from the original question (such as it was) whether the new class should be added, or the old class replaced.

Comment: You haven't given any details. What elements are you trying to find. What element do you want to add a class-name to? What's your mark-up? Do you want to *change* the class-name, or append another class-name?

Comment: Thanks for reply David. All I needed to it is: 
var el = $('.qa');
$(el[1]).addClass('qa2');